# YAML environment specific configurations

Tags: yaml

I have a need to mention either qal or prd in final url.
For this, I have 2 properties in my Configuration.yml file

> appEnv: qal

> apiProxy_BaseURL: https://cr-${appEnv}-apiproxy.com/rest/repo

But unfortunately, I am not getting value of 1st key into the value of 2nd key.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Note:
I am using SnakeYaml & Jackson(fasterxml) in my j2ee application inside tomee plus.
No usage of Sprint framework

Answer (score 0):

YAML is a data serialization language. It does not do any templating or string operations.

Other tools that employ YAML use a templating language to do things like this. You can either pre-process the input, i.e. let a templating engine run over it, then load the result with YAML, or post-process it, i.e. execute a templating language on each resulting string.

If you want to define and then use a variable, the former would be the simpler approach. If you want to reference other values based on their YAML path, the latter is what you want.

Spring [would do this for you](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.property-placeholders) but since you're not using it, you need to do it yourself by injecting a templating engine or building your own.